# Get notified about the critical memory usage / remaining available memory

Tags: c#, caching, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

What is the best ways to get notified about the critical memory usage / remaining available memory? I'm currently working on a cache implementation, where cache size should adapt dynamically to available memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification()` so that you will get notified when a full GC collection is imminent. See [Garbage Collection Notifications on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

This doesn't really tell you that memory is getting low, but it does give you a good place to check it. However, it doesn't tell you when a lot of memory has been freed up so it might not be totally useful for you.

You could also look into the [MemoryFailPoint class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx). This doesn't give you notifications, but it does let you determine if a memory allocation is likely to fail, before you actually allocate it.

Comment: Interesting. Do you think it makes sense to use `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification()` and in the callback to get the remaining available memory from a performance counter like `Memory/Available Bytes`?

Comment: @jrg Yes, I seem to remember someone doing that somewhere... Can't find the link tho' alas.